# Facebook signed app does not login

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I made a signed app.
When I login directly (without Facebook), the app accepts the user name and password and logs in successfully.
When I login through Facebook, the app fails (see screen shot).
I use the correct keyhash, getting it using the command form.
Can you see where I have a problem?

[image]

Comment: did you uploaded your released key hashes and also changes in mnifest for making released app

Comment: yes i have done  every thing,but i am not understand issue.

Comment: is your app have login enabled at developer.facebook.com with released key hashes

Comment: yes i have done this  also